# Not able to perform git pull upstream in git

Tags: git, github, pull-request, git-push

```
$ git merge abort
error: Merging is not possible because you have unmerged files.
hint: Fix them up in the work tree, and then use 'git add/rm <file>'
hint: as appropriate to mark resolution and make a commit.
fatal: Exiting because of an unresolved conflict.

Auto-merging web/app/info.sh
CONFLICT (content): Merge conflict in web/app/info.sh
Automatic merge failed; fix conflicts and then commit the result.

You have unmerged paths.
  (fix conflicts and run "git commit")
  (use "git merge --abort" to abort the merge)

Changes to be committed:
        modified:   README.md
```

I tried performing git pull upstream to branch in git bash, but I was receiving the following error. I had made changes only in one file but doing git fetch upstream and then git status can see that some README.md files are also appearing as uncommitted.
Tried: `git reset README.md`
Still not able to perform pull request. Above was the response that I received.

Comment: Your first block of text, starting with `git merge abort` and ending with `fatal: ...`, is from one command, where you told Git to merge the branch named `abort`. Did you mean to use `git merge --abort` here? The *second* block of text, `Auto-merging ...`, is from a *previous* `git merge` command, perhaps the one run by a `git pull` command. The *third* block, starting with `You have unmerged paths`, is from `git status`.

Comment: In any case, it seems clear that you need to learn how to work with `git merge`. I recommend *avoiding* the `git pull` command until you know exactly what `git fetch`, `git merge`, and `git rebase` each do. The `git pull` command just runs `git fetch` followed by your choice of the other two commands; to understand it, you need to understand these.